# Illustrator CC: Pixel perfect align Symbols and linked Documents

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, pixel, symbols

I am just trying to align created Symbols or linked docs in Illustrator to pixel. For some reason the "align to pixel"-option does apply to everything besides linked docs and symbols. Is there any work arround or do I have to adjust the position everytime I reposition my Symbols or linked docs?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

It may be your symbol not aligned properly in Grid to Grid pixel, if you are set the symbol to Grid no need to adjust every time.

see the difference

[image]

Comment: I found my mistake. The origin of my transformation was the center of the object.. that causes weir pixel position most of the time. But i still ahve the problem for linked documents

Answer (score 1):

Notice there are 2 places to call the align to pixel grid and they both must be checked:
[image]

Comment: I already enabled "align new objects to pixel grid" on the "new document" panel